# COMException when assigning to Excel.Application.ActivePrinter

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, com, comexception

I have a function, into which I'm passing an Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application instance. The function uses Windows' built in Fax printer, or the Microsoft XPS Document Writer, to save the file as a tiff image.

However, when I try to assign to the application's ActivePrinter property, a COMException with the following message is thrown:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Here's the code:

```
'Save the current default printer
Dim strDefaultPrinter As String = excelApp.ActivePrinter 

'Assign printer string constant to ActivePrinter - throws exception
excelApp.ActivePrinter = FAX_PRINTER

excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.PrintOutEx(, , , , , True, "c:\RestOfFilePath...") ' Print to file = true

'Reset the default printer
excelApp.ActivePrinter = strDefaultPrinter
```

The printers used are all confirmed as installed/in the registry. A similar function that takes a Word application class works fine.
I'm pretty new to COM related stuff, and I have a feeling this may just be my excel-related ignorance at play, but I can find almost nothing relating to this when searching google/stackoverflow, except for one or two old, unanswered threads. There are a few that relate to large amounts of data/large ranges, but not the ActivePrinter property

EDIT - A brief summary of the answer, detailed in M Patel's link:

Excel is picky about setting it's ActivePrinter property; instead of printer name alone, it requires both printer and port, e.g. "Fax on Ne01:".
This port should be available from the registry, either at:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices

or

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices

Using the method detailed in the link, or in my case using Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(). The latter will return something along the lines of "winspool,Ne01:". 
Concatenating the last part of that string on to the printer name in the manner "Fax on Ne01:", allows the ActivePrinter property to be set without the exception.

I should also note that my problem was occurring in excel 2010

Comment: The problem still exists in Excel 2013. And the concatenation string is translated with the user language in Excel. I've added my solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921150/c-sharp-setting-a-printer/32862651#32862651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the link below will help? It looks like the formatting of the name you assign to the ActivePrinter property matters.

http://netindonesia.net/blogs/jimmy/archive/2011/02/25/how-to-change-the-active-printer-to-specific-printer-in-excel-using-net-and-how-the-heck-can-i-find-the-right-printer-name-and-port-combination-that-excel-wants.aspx

Comment: That's the ticket, worked perfectly! And to think, I'd been poking around that exact part of the registry, but for reasons completely unrelated to this problem! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exception while printing the excel doc using excel interop.

With MS Word :-

```
document.Application.ActivePrinter = "Brother MFC.. Printer"; // Works without exception
```

But with MS Excel :-

```
document.Application.ActivePrinter = "Brother MFC.. Printer"; // throws COM exception
```

Below is a general function to print any office(MS Word, MS Excel, PS Powerpoint) document using office interop.

```
    void PrintToPrinter(dynamic app, dynamic document, string printer, int numberOfCopies)
    {
        bool PrintToFile = false;

        // Trying to print document without activation throws print exception
        document.Activate();

        // The only way to change printer is to set the default printer of document or of application
        // Remember the active printer name to reset after printing document with intended printer
        oldPrinterName = document.Application.ActivePrinter;

        for (int retry = 0; retry < retryLimit; retry++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!GetActivePrinter(document).Contains(printer))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        document.Application.ActivePrinter = printer;
                        docPrinterChanged = true;                            
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            app.ActivePrinter = printer;
                            appPrinterChanged = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                document.PrintOut(
                   true,            // Background
                   false,           // Append overwrite
                   oMissing,        // Page Range
                   oMissing,        // Print To File - OutputFileName
                   oMissing,        // From page
                   oMissing,        // To page
                   oMissing,        // Item
                   numberOfCopies,  // Number of copies to be printed
                   oMissing,        //
                   oMissing,        //
                   PrintToFile,     // Print To file
                   true             // Collate
                   );
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            if(docPrinterChanged)
                document.Application.ActivePrinter = oldPrinterName;
            else if(appPrinterChanged)
                app.ActivePrinter = oldPrinterName;   
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    private static string GetActivePrinter(dynamic document)
    {

        string activePrinter = document.Application.ActivePrinter;

        if (activePrinter.Length >= 0)
            return activePrinter;
        return null;
    }
```

When using the  above function for MS Excel I update the printer name as shown below. While passing the printer name to the above function from MS Excel instance, I use

```
    bool IFilePrint.PrintFile(string fullFileName, string printerName, int numberOfCopies)
    {

        // .......

        Excel.Workbook document = null;
        try
        {
            document = this.Application.Workbooks.Open(fullFileName);
        }
        catch
        {
            document = null;
        }

        string portNumber = null;

        // Find correct printerport
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(fullFileName))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                object value = key.GetValue(printerName);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    string[] values = value.ToString().Split(',');
                    if (values.Length >= 2) port = values[1];
                }
            }
        }

        // Get current concatenation string ('on' in en, 'auf' in de, etc..)
        var split = this.Application.ActivePrinter.Split(' ');
        if (split.Length >= 3)
            printerName = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", printerName, split[split.Length - 2], port);

        PrintToPrinter(this.Application, document, printerName, numberOfCopies);

        // ...........
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
        result = true;   
        return result;
    }
```

Further check on this can done:

1) Check if the intended printer exists using PrinterSettings class.

2) (Print to file) Check if intended print option is To PDF/ To XPS / FAX etc.