# C# Excel ActivePrinter Exception 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, printing, automation

I cannot change the Active Printer to Specific Printer in Excel from Asp.NET web-service. The service is running under LocalSystem account. 
If I call a function which shows a list of printers:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
```

I get a list of installed in system printers:

> "Microsoft Print to PDF"
>
> "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
>
> "HP Universal Printing PCL 6"

But if I call function

```
excelApplication.ActivePrinter
```

It returns -

> unknown printer

When I try to set printer from this [c# setting a printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921150/c-sharp-setting-a-printer):

```
excelApplication.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
```

or (I found Port in register hive **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices**)

```
excelApplication.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer on Ne00:"
```

It doesn't matter, I get the Exception 0x800A03EC.

Finally, I also tried to change the default printer in the system:

```
 [DllImport("winspool.drv",
              CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
              SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern Boolean SetDefaultPrinter(String name);
```

It works fine, default printer in system has changed. But in the Excel still "unknown printer"

Also if I open the Excel under my account, in print settings I can see the default printer

Comment: Have your ASP.NET's site Application Pool run under a dedicated domain user - I'd not recommend fiddling with LocalsSystems's privileges to get this to work.

Comment: OK, thanks for replay. I try to change my accaount to NetworkService